# How to Remove anchor Node on camera focus out

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I am developing an app where on image detection I am playing a video as anchor node. Everything is working perfect except video stoping on camera focus out. I can hear audio from video playing even if I move camera away from detected image. I have tried augmented image tracking state stop but it did not help.

Is there any callback or observer where I can check if camera is not focusing on augmented image?

Comment: Have you got anything for this ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no call-back available at this time - this type of thing has been discussed on the ARCore issues list and it was noted that it is outside the scope of ARCore: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/78

You can, however, check yourself by mapping your nodes world points to screen point and then checking if it is within the 'arSceneView.scene.camera' view bounds - see below for values for x and y which will indicate if it is outside the view, from the ARCore documentation:  https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/Camera#worldToScreenPoint(com.google.ar.sceneform.math.Vector3)

> **public Vector3 worldToScreenPoint (Vector3 point)**
>
> Convert a point from world space into screen space.
>
> The X value is negative when the point is left of the viewport, between 0 and the width of the SceneView when the point is within the viewport, and greater than the width when the point is to the right of the viewport.
>
> The Y value is negative when the point is below the viewport, between 0 and the height of the SceneView when the point is within the viewport, and greater than the height when the point is above the viewport.
>
> The Z value is always 0 since the return value is a 2D coordinate.